# How Do I Restore a Hive Managed Table That Has Been Deleted by Mistake?

Tags: hive, hdfs

1. I created an managed table with the following sql and added data to it

```
CREATE TABLE test.internal_table (
  id INT,
  name STRING
);
INSERT INTO TABLE test.internal_table VALUES
  (1, 'John'),
  (2, 'Jane'),
  (3, 'Bob'),
  (4, 'Alice'),
  (5, 'Charlie'),
  (6, 'Diana'),
  (7, 'Eva'),
  (8, 'Frank'),
  (9, 'Grace'),
  (10, 'Henry');
```

2. i turned on the HDFS Trash
   `fs.trash.interval=360`
3. then i execute “drop table test.internal_table” SQL
4. I found the data files of the deleted internal_table table in the /user/hive/.Trash/Current/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/internal_table path
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QExpE.png)
5. so How do I recover the test.internal_table ?

I tried the following 5 methods:

1. Run the '**hdfs dfs mv**' command to move the deleted data files to the /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db path,then executed 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM test.internal_table' SQL,But it didn't work
2. First, executed DDL SQL **recreated test.internal_table**，then Ran the '**hdfs dfs mv**' command to move the deleted data files to the /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db path,But it didn't work
   3.First, executed DDL SQL recreated test.internal_table,Moved the deleted data files back to the test.internal_table storage path,then Ran the '**msck repair table internal_table**;' command,But it didn't work
3. executed '**LOAD DATA INPATH **'/user/hive/.Trash/Current/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/internal_table/' INTO TABLE internal_table;' to load the deleted data file into the table,But it didn't work
4. ​
    Try to move the deleted data file to /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/internal_table, and then run the following commands:

CREATE TABLE test.internal_table (
id INT,
name STRING
)**location '/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/test.db/internal_table'**;

It didn't work either, and the data still hasn't been recovered.

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring back the data to the table location and then run MSCK repair

```
    MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>;
```